# Inserting data from HTML form into MySQL using PDO in PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, pdo

I'm currently learning to code and grappling with how to use PDO correctly to build a PHP/MySQL based app. The following code is supposed to take user data from an HTML form and insert into the database, but when the form is submitted page goes blank, no error message is returned and nothing is added to the database.

All advice gratefully received:

```
<?php
if ( empty( $_POST ) ){
?>
<form name='registration' action='user_register.php' method='POST'>
<label for 'title'>Title: </label>
<input type="text" name="title" />

<label for 'url'>URL: </label>
<input type="text" name="url" />

<label for 'contact'>Contact: </label>
<input type="text" name="contact" />

<label for 'category'>Category: </label>
<input type="text" name="category" />

<label for 'location'>Location: </label>
<input type="text" name="location" />

<label for 'founded'>Founded: </label>
<input type="text" name="founded" />

<label for 'rss'>RSS: </label>
<input type="text" name="rss" />

<label for 'twitter'>Twitter: </label>
<input type="text" name="twitter" />

<label for 'facebook'>Facebook: </label>
<input type="text" name="facebook" />

<label for 'google'>Google: </label>
<input type="text" name="google" />

<label for 'youtube'>YouTube: </label>
<input type="text" name="youtube" />

<label for 'pinterest'>Pinterest: </label>
<input type="text" name="pinterest" />

<label for 'instagram'>Instagram: </label>
<input type="text" name="instagram" />


<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

<?php
} else {

try {

$db_user = 'testuser';
$db_pass = 'testpassword';
$db = new PDO( 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdatabase', $db_user, $db_pass );

$form = $_POST;
$title = $form[ 'title' ];
$url = $form[ 'url' ];
$contact = $form[ 'contact' ];
$category = $form[ 'category' ];
$location = $form[ 'location' ];
$founded = $form[ 'founded' ];
$rss = $form[ 'rss' ];
$twitter = $form[ 'twitter' ];
$facebook = $form[ 'facebook' ];
$google = $form[ 'google' ];
$youtube = $form[ 'youtube' ];
$pinterest = $form[ 'pinterest' ];
$instagram = $form[ 'instagram' ];

$sql = "INSERT INTO testtable ( 
    title, url, contact, category, location, 
    founded, rss, twitter, facebook, 
    google, youtube, pinterest, instagram ) 
    VALUES ( 
    :title, :url, :contact, :category, 
    :location, :founded, :rss, :twitter, 
    :facebook, :google, :youtube, :pinterest, :instagram )";

$query = $db->prepare( $sql );
$query->execute( array( ':title'=>$title, ':url'=>$url, ':contact'=>$contact, ':category'=>$category, ':location'=>$location, ':founded'=>$founded, ':rss'=>$rss, ':twitter'=>$twitter, ':facebook'=>$facebook, ':google'=>$google, ':youtube'=>$youtube, ':pinterest'=>$pinterest, ':instagram'=>$instagram ) );

}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
echo $e->getMessage();
}
}

?>
```

Comment: I don't think this would make a difference, but you don't need colons in front of the parameters in your `execute()` call. E.g. change `':title' => $title` to `'title' => $title`.

Comment: There might be a database connectivity error, I suggest to enable the php error temporarily and retry and see if any errors are being thrown. 

ini_set('display_errors', 1)

Comment: @user2668563 can you `var_dump($form);` and `echo $sql;`?

Comment: I just picked that up from the tutorials I worked through - I've tried it without the colons, but you're right, it didn't make any difference.

Comment: @GeorgeBrighton PHP automatically adds the colon prefix if you omit it

Comment: @Phil I'm not sure that's the right way to think about it, or how it works behind the scenes - probably just saying both ways are accepted is more accurate.

Comment: @GeorgeBrighton It's definitely how it works behind the scenes - https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/pdo/pdo_stmt.c#L363

Comment: @Lancey does you database have all the right columns?

Comment: @Phil Thanks for that - learnt something new :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, here's my take...

You probably have an error somewhere and are not reporting them properly for development purposes (hence the blank screen).

Make sure your `php.ini` file has the following key / value pairs

```
error_reporting = E_ALL
display_errors = On
```

If you have to make any changes, you'll need to restart your web server.

Another thing you should do is set PDO to throw exceptions. Change your connection line to...

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdatabase;charset=utf8', $db_user, $db_pass, array(
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
```

I'd also add some form of feedback after executing your query so you at least know something happened, eg

```
$query->execute(...);
printf('<p>Inserted %d row</p>', $query->rowCount());
```

And finally, remove the `try` and entire `catch` block. PHP exceptions contain valuable information for debugging. Once you're ready for production, you can implement a more global error / exception handling mechanism but for now, I'd just let the exceptions bubble up and terminate your program.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a syntax error on line 4:

```
<form name='registration' action='user_register.php' method='POST'/>
```

Becomes:

```
<form name='registration' action='user_register.php' method='POST'>
```

Edit: As someone mentioned this won't actually stop your form from submitting.

I've stared at your code for a while and I can't see any reason why it wouldn't work. The problem is probably somewhere else.

Do very basic tests to make sure your technologies are working. I'd start by writing a simple 4-line script that writes one value to one column in one table in a prepared statement, just to make sure PDO and MySQL are online.

Comment: Indeed - it makes the HTML invalid, but the POST data submitted is perfectly fine.

Comment: I'm surprised this isn't the right solution. Self-closing the form would (in my mind) remove all input fields from the POST payload. Might act differently across browsers

Comment: Thanks - I got rid of the stray slash, but it's still behaving the same way. I think Chrome just ignored it.

Comment: Just because this doesn't fix the main problem doesn't mean it deserves a downvote.

Answer (score 0):

What is the file you are working on called?

```
action='user_register.php'
```

maybe it is going blank because user_register.php isn't the right file name?

try

```
action='<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>'
```

Comment: Definitely the right file name, although I tried this code just in case, but still receiving the same problem.

Comment: @user2668563 I'm all out of ideas :/

Answer (score 0):

i think refering these might help,

[Inserting data into MySQL with PHP PDO by HTML forms](http://goo.gl/ES5MvD)
[Starting with PDO](http://goo.gl/XgtXLu)

Answer (score -1):

```
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
```

should be

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

*at least I think so, someone please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Unfortunately not - `<button type="submit">` will submit the form correctly.

Comment: @GeorgeBrighton thanks for the info! my eyes haven't seen it like that before. good to know.

Comment: Thanks - I tried it with the suggested alternative, but it made no difference to the code's behaviour.